# ClassNotFoundException in ActionListerner

Tags: java, jdbc, packaging, classnotfoundexception

I have the following error unreported exception `ClassNotFoundException` in my button action Listener and I'm unsure how i can resolve it, I tried adding Throw `ClassNotFoundException` but it was still giving me an error when trying to compile, I added it at

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throw ClassNotFoundException {
//action listeners for Login in button and menu item
        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {

                    DisplaySearch.Search(jtfImagename.getText(), jtfLocation.getText(), jtfTimestamp.getText());

                    String Iname = jtfImagename.getText();
                    String Loc = jtfLocation.getText();
                    String Time = jtfTimestamp.getText();
                    accountReportArea.setText("Search Criteria \n" + "Image name : " + Iname + "\nLocation : " + Loc + "\nTime Stamp : " + Time);                 
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    //    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    //            "Sorry, couldn't check your credentials. Check the logs and report the problem to an administrator.");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

DisplaySearch {
    // database URL                              

    static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
    static final String USERNAME = "root";
    static final String PASSWORD = "root";

    // launch the application
    public static void Search(String imageName, String DateStamp, String imageTag) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Connection connection = null; // manages connection
        Statement statement = null; // query statement
        ResultSet resultSet = null; // manages results

        // connect to database books and query database
        try {
            // establish connection to database
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // create Statement for querying database
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            // query database                                        
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                    "SELECT imageName, DateStamp, imageTag FROM images");

            // process query results   
            System.out.println("Search Criteria");

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String Tag = resultSet.getString(imageTag);
                String Date = resultSet.getString(DateStamp);
                String Name = resultSet.getString(imageName);
                System.out.print("Image Name: " + Name);
                System.out.print(", Date: " + Date);
                System.out.print(", Tag: " + Tag);
            } // end while
        } // end try
        catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        } // end catch                                                     
        finally // ensure resultSet, statement and connection are closed
        {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
                statement.close();
                connection.close();
            } // end try                                               
            catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            } // end catch                                             
        } // end finally                                              
    } // end main
} // end class
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: `DisplaySearch.Search(jtfImagename.getText(), jtfLocation.getText(), jtfTimestamp.getText());`

Comment: Why did you write `Throw` instead of `throw`? Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: Adding `throws ClassNotFoundException` won't solve your problem. If it's an RCP application, please make sure that you've added all the necessary plug-ins to the product configuration.

Answer (score 1):

By adding `throws ClassNotFoundException` you won't solve any problems. You just indicate to someone who call this function, it *could*  throw such an exception.

Since you are using `Class.forName()` you should include `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` at run-time. Maybe a JAR is missing in your classpath?

Comment: I have `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` Do i need to add it to my gui as well?

Comment: This line is intended to create a `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` instance. Thus, the `.class` file should be included when running your program. Do you have a file called `mysql-connector-java-x.x.x-bin.jar` in your classpath?

Comment: Yes i have the connect in my classpath.